# JIRA API error when trying to pull details when field is empty

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I am using the JIRA API to pull ticket details and put it in a separate database that I can connect Tableau to.
My problem is that when pulling in a ticket details (using python) where e.g. it has no priority, that I get an error.
How do I get around that error? How can I handle this error?

Just currently testing by printing the details on-screen:

```
for issue in issues:
if verbose:
            print( "issue.key: ", issue.key );
            print( "issue.fields.project.id: ", issue.fields.project.id );
```

The error I get is:

> cursor.execute(sql_stmt, (issue.key, issue.fields.issuetype.name,
>   issue.fields.project.name, issue.fields.summary,
>   issue.fields.updated,issue.fields.priority.name)) AttributeError: type
>   object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'priority

Answer (score 1):

Catch the AttributeError

```
for issue in issues:
    if verbose:
        try:
            print( "issue.key: ", issue.key );
            print( "issue.fields.project.id: ", issue.fields.project.id );
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Karimtabet.
It seems though that the following worked better:

```
if verbose:
    try:
        print( "issue.key: ", issue.key );
        print( "issue.fields.project.id: ", issue.fields.project.id );
    except AttributeError:
        key = None
```